# Why gzip is not consistent?

Tags: python-3.x, ascii, gzip

Why these lines won't give me identical results?

```
>>> gzip.compress('same'.encode('ascii'))
b'\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\xe2\x0e0V\x02\xff+N\xccM\x05\x00D\xf1P\xfc\x04\x00\x00\x00'
>>> gzip.compress('same'.encode('ascii'))
b'\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\xe3\x0e0V\x02\xff+N\xccM\x05\x00D\xf1P\xfc\x04\x00\x00\x00'
```

This is quite annoying for unit testing.

Comment: I think the gzip header contains a timestamp

Comment: This is not related to python.  You can see the same thing running gzip from the command line.

Comment: I've made the exact same code in node.js, and it's consistent.

Comment: The first 10 bytes represent the basic gzip header, which includes `mtime`. See details in [rfc1952](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1952#page-5). Inconsistent results during automated testing could also be related to the OS-dependent resolution of `mtime`, as explained in the note [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.stat_result).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gzip header contains a modification timestamp.
See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html#gzip.GzipFile.mtime)

For unit testing, you might be able to get away with skipping the header and comparing the rest.

Something like this:

```
a = gzip.compress('same'.encode('ascii'))
b = gzip.compress('same'.encode('ascii'))

a[5:] == b[5:]
```

Not sure about the value 5 in that but that seems to be the header size it is using.

Comment: How can I get rid of the timestamp? Or force it to a certain value?

Comment: I don't think `gzip` provides a way to omit the timestamp, so you can just slice off the header as shown in my edit.

Comment: I can force `mtime` to be 0, suits me.

Comment: @andars: `gzip.GZipFile()` has `mtime` parameter that you can pass explicitly. The timestamp is at 4..8 bytes: `ts = int.from_bytes(gzipped[4:8], 'little')`.

Comment: Somehow missed that. Good to know. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As noted, the gzip header contains a timestamp. If you pass the -n or --no-name  option (to the command-line zip program) these are omitted.